# open build-in android image viewer in webview

Tags: android, webview

First I want download all files. so I use `setDownloadListener` functions and it works!

Also I want webview Handling Page Navigation ( internal links open within the WebView) ... but not if it is a file!

for example if url is 'www.example.com' it open within the WebView but
if url is 'www.example.com/file.mp4' it open with external application!
(I rather it open with default android media player!)

Also for 'www.example.com/file.jpg' I rather open with build-in android image viewer!

So I try coding:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                        long contentLength) {
                // handle download, here we use brower to download, also you can try other approach.
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.contains(".mp4") || url.contains(".jpg")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
                else if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.example.com")) {
                    // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
                    return false;
                }
                // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }

        });


        webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

when I click image or video link, I have 2 choice:

1- open with external browsers
2- open with webview (my app)

So I have 2 problem:

1- It must not suggest me "open with webview (my app)" ... It must only suggest me external app... .. so how can I do it?

2- I want open native build-in image viewver (for mp4 link) and video player in android (for jpg link)....not external browser!

please help me correct my code...**at least a solution for first problem!**